# Matplotlib crashes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm try to learn data visualization with matplotlib, but it keeps crashing whenever I try the plot function:

```
>>> import pylab
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> names1880 = pd.read_csv('/root/yob1880.txt', names=['name', 'sex', 'births']) 
>>> pieces = [] 
>>> for year, group in names.groupby(['year', 'sex']):
...     pieces.append(group.sort_index(by='births', ascending=False)[:1000])
...     top1000 = pd.concat(pieces, ignore_index=True)
>>> table = top1000.pivot_table(rows='year', cols='sex', aggfunc=sum)
>>> table.plot(title='Sum of table1000 by year and sex',
     yticks=np.linspace(0, 1.2, 13), xticks=range(1880, 2020, 10))
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are  supported
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x3063610>
```

I'm running Kali Linux 1.0.7 The data frame looks fine, my code runs fine until I attempt to plot it, so why am I getting that error every time, I try using the pylab.show() function and it doesn't even plot the line?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with Qt not Matplotlib. What happens when you run qtcreator or something similar? If that fails than you probably need to rebuild Qt.